# How to predict input parameters from target parameter in a machine learning model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

For example if the experimental input data like T=300 C, time= 60 min, Catalyst= Type A gives 70% biodiesel yield, I want the ANN model to predict what the input parameters to achieve 90 or even 95% biodiesel yield?

I have not found a way to solve it.